# How to mimic datagridview loading in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, .net-3.5

If you load a ton of records the DataGridView stays responsive as it loads records to the DataGridView bit by bit.  How can this be done with a regular DataGridView and set of data coming from a database (I can't use straight data binding due to our data access layer).

Comment: you should be more specific, you have lots of rows and it takes time to bind to gridview or you want to load grid  via ajax to make it responsive?

Comment: Is the for the Winforms datagridview? If you could add the winforms tag that would make it clearer.

Comment: this is a winforms datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you will almost certainly want to implement paging at your data access layer to return small sets of data from the database.

Once you have that you can then consider either implementing user controlled paging (where they click a button to show the next or previous page - much like here on StackOverflow) or automatic paging.

For automatic paging (like you see in Excel) you need to implement Virtual mode in the DataGridView. There is quite a good example of this in this [blog post](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/TPeplow/archive/2009/07/14/datagridview-paging-using-virtual-mode.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your data access layer needs to yield results before completing the query. It should implement IEnumerable or IDataReader. Then when you bind to it the first page of results should appear quickly.

Write a unit test that fetches only the first row, and a second unit test that fetches all rows. If both unit test take the same amount of time then you have problem in your DAL. Change your DAL so it yields rows early.

Comment: The Data Access Layer does implement IEnumerable, I was under the impression it had to use IList to use data binding in a DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use paging and only query necessary number of rows per page from database? 
[check this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/large_data_gridview_part1.aspx)

Comment: Per requirements from my boss, No